# Webpack's file loader doesn't update path to the assets in the HTML file

Tags: javascript, webpack

So, in my pug template I have:

```
img(src="../img/myimage.png", alt="image")
```

I import this image in my script. It does proceed the file to the folder assets/files with correct name and hash, but it doesn't update src attribute in the output HTML file. It stays like this:

```
<img src="../img/myimage.png" alt="image">
```

Here is module.rules:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "html-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: ["pug-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /(manifest.json)|(^old\/.+)|(\.(png|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|mp4|ico|svg|webp))$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name]-[hash].[ext]",
              outputPath: "assets/files"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `publicPath` inside of file loader:

```
      {
        test: /(manifest.json)|(^old\/.+)|(\.(png|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|mp4|ico|svg|webp))$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name]-[hash].[ext]",
              outputPath: "assets/files",
              publicPath: "some/path"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```